# dllimport how to get which application called function in unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, c++, callback, dllimport, dllexport

I have **1 unmanaged C++ dll** with **dllexport** functions and **3 managed C# application** that use unmanaged dll functions with **dllimport** , okay everything works fine.

I need to know in C++ dll , How can I get a value that tells me which C# application called it from outside.

**please look at image below :**

[image: dll image]

> - now,when **client.exe** calls **function1** from unmanaged dll , a message    shows up **"client.exe called me!"**
> - now,when **console.exe** calls **function1** from unmanaged dll , a message    shows up **"console.exe called me!"**
> - now,when **pure.exe** calls **function1** from unmanaged dll , a message    shows up **"pure.exe called me!"**

I need unmanaged library finds out it by its own, I don't want send anything extra from C# application like getting C# file path and send it to function.

**Can it be possible? if yes , How can I do it?**

Comment: Technically the function should be generic and should not act based on which process is calling it. But if you have 3 different ways of doing stuff, then you should have 3 different functions exported and from each C# application call the respective ones.

Comment: It is technically possible to get information about the process (i.e, the calling exe) in which the library function is called and executed, but then again, i very much agree with Soundararajan here...

Comment: Take a look at the `Assembly` class. IIRC there's a function provided to do that.

Comment: Guys, we should be asking the OP why he wants to do it, rather than telling him that he shouldn't.  For all we know, he might want to log the name of the calling app for some reason.

Comment: A DLL runs in the same process as the caller. So you just need an API call to [get the current process ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessid)

Comment: @Soundararajan  I need the calling exe filename for some security reasons and my blockchain , thanks.

Comment: @PaulSanders yeah exactly ! I need it for log and blockchain system.

Comment: Hi @charley manson, hope I don’t start a debate on security here, and I know it seems your question was already replied, but If you are using the calling application (name, token, etc) for security reasons, beware of [RemoteThreads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethreadex) and [Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
constexpr DWORD bufsize = 32768;
WCHAR *calling_application = new WCHAR [bufsize];
DWORD nSize = GetModuleFileNameW (NULL, calling_application, bufsize);

if (nSize == 0 || nSize == bufsize)
{
    // panic, should never happen
}

// ...

delete [] calling_application;
```

Documentation here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: thank you a lot Paul , I'm checking it I will back and accept your answer if it works for me

Comment: You need to check for errors also, and I don't really understand the `+ 1`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can there be any errors?  And 1 for luck :) (or end of string marker)

Comment: `MAX_PATH` includes space for terminator when using standard paths. So the `+ 1` is pointless. When long file names are enabled (greater than `MAX_PATH`), then the call can fail if the path is too long. You can find this out by reading the documentation.

Comment: @David Fine, edited. Perhaps you'd like to reverse your downvote. Overly long filenames play havoc with Explorer so these are unlikely to be an issue but I changed the code anyway.